# Is it possible to detect iBeacon in a web app?

Tags: angular, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I understand that iBeacon advertisement scanning is not implemented in the Web Bluetooth API (which currently works only in Chrome-based browsers). However, is there any possibility to access low-level device APIs through bootstrapping an Angular app into something like Electron?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately,.no.  Any code that might attempt to access low-level Bluetooth APIs through a browser would essentially be exploiting a security vulnerability. Even if one is found (and I am not aware of any that exist) it would be browser and platform-specific and would be subject to closure if discovered by the browser manufacturer.

Since Web Bluetooth does not support arbitrary scanning, pure web apps simply cannot scan for Bluetooth beacons.  Hybrid technologies like ReactNative or Ionic with appropriate plugins to access the native Bluetooth functionality are as close as you can come with web technologies.